# Quaternion-Sasakian manifolds and special holonomy Sasakian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holonomy, sasakian-geometry

Two well-known slogans are

**A Sasakian manifold is the odd dimensional analogue of a Kähler manifold**

and

**A $3$-Sasakian manifold is the odd dimensional analogue of a hyper-Kähler manifold**

Does this analogy extend to quaternion-Kähler manifolds? Is there a notion of quaternion-Sasakian manifolds?

What about special holonomy? Does there exist a notion of $Spin(7)$-Sasakian manifold. What about $G_2$-holonomy?

Can one use find an even dimensional analogue?

Answer (score 2):

Nearly-Kahler manifold are the 6-dimensional links of G2-cones,
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearly_K%C3%A4hler_manifold

I do not know about the others

Comment: There is a similar result between dimensions $7$ and $8$ too.